# how to load a cookie file in a requests session

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

I want load into a request session a cookie that is in a file cookies.txt. I have tried the following way:

```
cookie_file='/home/user/cookies.txt'
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    audi_cookie = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar()
    s.cookies = audi_cookie.load(filename=cookie_file, ignore_expires=True)
    r_login = s.get(myurl)
```

with or without ignore_expires, or in this

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    audi_cookie = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar(filename=cookie_file)
    s.cookies = audi_cookie.load(ignore_expires=True)
    r_login = s.get(myurl)
```

in the above way I have got:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extract_cookies'
```

Also I have tried:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    audi_cookie = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar(filename=cookie_file)
    s.cookies = audi_cookie
    r_login = s.get(myurl)
```

but does not work, I mean it returns the access page without authentication.

I have also tried http.cookiejar.FileCookieJar instead of MozillaCookieJar